# Fill an array with clones of a single object

Tags: java, arrays, collections, clone

What is a quick and easy way to fill a Java array with clones of a single object?

e.g. after:

```
Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[N];
fillWithClones(rectangles, new Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

the `rectangles` array would contain N distinct `Rectangle` instances, initialised with the same coordinates.

I am aware of the flaws of `Object.clone()` in Java, but in this case I know that the objects to be copied have non-throwing, public `clone()` methods but may or may not have a public copy constructor.

I'm guessing there is a library method somewhere that does this, but I don't think it's in the JDK, Commons-collections or Guava.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the specific type you want to work with at compile time, you will have to invoke the `clone` method by reflection.

```
private static <T> T cloneByReflection(T object) {
    try {
        return (T) object.getClass().getMethod("clone").invoke(object);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;    // or whatever you want to do
    }
}

public static <T> void fillWithClones(T[] array, T template) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
        array[i] = cloneByReflection(template);
}
```

Comment: The second method signature should be simplified to `public static void fillWithClones(Object[] array, Object template)`

Answer (score 0):

For rectangles:

```
public void fillWithClones(Rectangle[] arr, Rectangle src) {
    for(int xa=0,len=arr.length; xa<len; xa++) { arr[xa]=(Rectangle)src.clone(); }
    }
```

Comment: For types unknown, `Object.clone` is protected. You can only access that method via reflection (and only if the target type defines a public override, of course).

Comment: @Chris: Crap, what a screw-up Clonable is.  I deleted the incorrect untyped method.

Answer (score 0):

@Chris Jester-Young answer gives you a recipe for doing what you want to do.

But I'd suggest that there is something rather wrong about an application that does this sort of thing.

- Why does your application *need* to make deep copies of arrays of random things?  If you don't know the things' types, how do you know that copying is necessary?
- What is your application supposed to do when the array contains a non-clonable object?  Do you throw an exception?  Do you put a `null` in the array, requiring later null checking?

It is better design to have all of the objects that you may want to clone implement an interface with a (public) clone method method.  That way you can have a statically typed solution (no dynamic type exceptions!) and you can avoid the overheads of invoking `clone` reflectively.

Comment: The types are not "random".  The type is known in each case, but I would prefer a generic method to keep the program smaller.  Some of the classes are from the JDK so I cannot define a new interface for them.  If this method encounters a non-cloneable object it should throw a `CloneNotSupportedException`.

Comment: @finnw - what about the first bullet?  Why does your application need to clone objects in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

If a copy constructor *might* exist (and you want to use it if it does), you could do something like this:

**(Edit: Updated code to use an array instead of List):**

```
private static <T> void fillWithClones( T[] array, T object )
{
  try
  {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>)object.getClass();
    Constructor<T> c = clazz.getConstructor( object.getClass() );

    try
    {
      for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
      {
        array[i] = (T)c.newInstance( object );
      }
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
      // Handle exception or rethrow...
    }
  }
  catch ( NoSuchMethodException e )
  {
    // No copy constructor, try clone option...
  }
}
```

Some of the exception handling could be tidied up, of course.

Comment: A constructor `T(T)` is not necessarily a copy constructor (e.g. `JFrame`, `JScrollPane`, `ClassLoader`, `Properties`, `Throwable`.)

Comment: @finnw: Yeah, good pickup. I guess at the end of the day you need to know _something_ about the objects you're duplicating to choose an appropriate solution.

Comment: Generics has no effect here. Just do `private static void fillWithClones( Object[] array, Object object )` and change the `T` to `?`