# Java: Making a copy of an object when you only have access to an interface

Tags: java, interface, clone

I am using an API that gives access to a certain set of subclasses with a common interface. I use the interface throughout my code, and the instances are resolved to the proper subclass based on user needs. My problem is that I need to create a copy of one of these objects,  but I don't have access to the clone() method and the API doesn't provide a copy constructor.
ie:

```
ObjectInterface myObject = objectFromParameter.clone(); //Not possible...
```

Is there a workaround in Java?

Comment: Do the implementing classes also implement `Cloneable`, or is this also unknown?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300692/fill-an-array-with-clones-of-a-single-object

Comment: No they do not implement Cloneable unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iYou might be able to do what you want with reflection. Alternatively, If the object supports serialization, you can serialize to a byte array and then reconstruct a new instance from that.

Comment: Serializing and deserializing is a good idea. However, it wouldn't work as expected if one of the implementing classes is an enumeration (unlikely).

Comment: Yes I think reflection might work. Not very elegant, but it's better than nothing. I think I may need to rethink my architecture as a whole however. When I run into a problem of language limitation, its usually because there is a better way to accomplish the overall goal.